# Internet Explorer cuts out text thru semi-transparent div background

Tags: jquery, html, background, fadeout, antialiasing

Well, to be honest I don't really event know how to describe this other than:

"Why does this not work in IE8 but just fine in Firefox or Chrome":
http://jsfiddle.net/iddqd/xEfSK/

But, I'll try:
So it looks fine when it's not animating and there seem to be two issues. One is that IE doesn't use anti-aliasing when fading and the second one is that the text somehow cuts through the semi-transparent div.

I've tried various hacks like removing the filter with a callback function, putting the text in a separate div, putting the whiteBackground outside of box. Out of all combinations i couldn't find a working solution.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short and simple answer is that IE8 and lower do not support `opacity` nor any kind of transparency emulators such as `rgba()` coloring. It can only emulate this by using a (now deprecated) `filter` syntax to invoke DirectX rendering internally. This is what jQuery attempts to do internally to give the 'best possible sort-of-intended result', but yes, it will look uglier since DirectX filters operate on images, so the browser has to render internally and pass it on, thus creating 2 problems:

- Anti-aliasing is twitchy because ClearType cannot be applied
- Because DirectX tries to render on top it might have stacking issues, such as separate layers not always appearing in the right order during transitions

You describe both problems, which are regrettably normal with the filter-hack. You can find some possible solutions [on this page](http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/), but in general I'd just accept that this won't work properly on IE<=8, and/or degrade gracefully to skip the fade in those browsers.